# An exercise about Lebesgue measure on compact sets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ and $F$ two compact subsets of  $\mathbb{R}$ such tha $E$$\subset$$F$ and
$\mu$$(E)$$<$$\mu$$(F)$.
Prove that $\forall$$a$$\in$$($$\mu$$(E)$,$\mu$$(F)$$)$ we can find a compact set $K$ such that $E$$\subset$$K$$\subset$$F$ and $\mu$$(K)$$=a$.

I came up with the idea of constructing a continuous function on the interval $($$\mu$$(E)$,$\mu$$(F)$$)$ and using the intermediate value theorem. Maybe this is a wrong idea but I am stuck.

Can someone help me ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a thought : let $b=a-\lambda(E)$, maybe you can construct $K$ as a $r$-neighborhood of the set $E$ (which gives $\lambda(K)\geq \lambda(E)$) and adjust the "radius" $r$ such that $\lambda(K)-\lambda(E) = b$.

Comment: thats interesting.But i need K to be compact ,so with your idea maybe i can to construct K as the closure of an r-neighborhood of E e.t.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $r \ge 0,$ let $E_r=\{x\in F: d(x,E)\le r\}.$ Show each $E_r$ is compact. Define $f(r) = \mu(E_r).$ Then $f(0) = \mu(E)$ and $f(r)=\mu(F)$ for large enough $r.$ If you show $f$ is continuous, you'll be done by the IVT. For continuity you'll want to use "continuity properties of measures", along with the fact that $\mu(\{x\in F: d(x,E)= r\}) =0$ for $r>0.$

Comment: thank you! thats a very nice hint.!